# Unable to get AJAX's post values (plain Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, todataurl

I'm aware that this question was answered in this forum ([Unable to get values in POST php web serivce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563588/unable-to-get-values-in-post-php-web-serivce)), but both the question and the answer used jQuery and, in my case, I can't use it (no matter why)...

So, I have a Javascript file that is intended to make a canvas' "screen capture" (using the "toDataURL()" function) and send it to a PHP file using AJAX. As the data to be sent is really long, I can't use the "GET" method (AJAX returns a 414 error: "URL TOO LONG"), so I need to use "POST".

I've followed some examples on **plain Javascript** (which are by no means easy to find, because everyone uses jQuery! :P) and my code looks like this:

```
var dataURL = me.video.getScreenCanvas().toDataURL();

var req = false;
try{
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
// IE
try{
    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    // try an older version
    try{
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e){
    return false;
    }
}
}

req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req .readyState == 4){
    if(req.status == 200)
    { 
        console.log("RESULT AJAX: "+req.responseText);
    }else{ 
        console.log("ERROR AJAX: returned status code "+req.status+" "+req.statusText); 
    }
    }
}

req.open("POST", "http://www.mywebpage.com/image_upload.php", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send("imgdata="+dataURL);
```

When trying to log the content of the "dataURL" variable, it logs a large string like "image/png...blablabla", so I presume the data is generated as expected.

At this moment, the PHP file just tries to retrieve the result:

```
<?php

$imageData = '';

if(isset($_POST['imgdata']))
{
    echo "correct POST!";
    $imageData = $_POST['imgdata'];
}else if(isset($_GET['imgdata'])){
    echo "correct GET!";
    $imageData = $_GET['imgdata'];
}

echo "ImgData: ".$imageData;

if($imageData != '')
{
    $imageData = str_replace(' ','+',$imageData);
    $decodedData = base64_decode($imageData);

    if(file_put_contents('imatge1.jpeg', $decodedData) !== FALSE)
    {
        echo "Image has been successfully processed...?";
    }else{
        echo "Error trying to process the image...";
    }
}

?>
```

However, the PHP file doesn't echo the "POST" nor the "GET" messages, the "ImgData" echo returns empty and no "success" nor "error while processing image" message is echoed... So **it seems that the PHP file is not able to retrieve the data** passed by AJAX's "POST" method.

What am I doing wrong? How could I solve this problem using just **plain Javascript** (**it's important not to use jQuery**)?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort! :)

Comment: what is the reply message in console?

Comment: 1. Do a simple `var_dump($_POST)` on top of your PHP script, to see if you are getting _anything_. 2. Look at the request in your browser’s developer tools, anything conspicuous there?

Comment: The "var_dump" returned "array(0){ }", so I guess the PHP script is getting nothing at all... I can't use the browser's developer tools because I'm running this things from a mobile app (not run in a web browser)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your javascript, and tested this,  please try if it work with you :

```
function create_XHR(){
    var XHR = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try {
            XHR = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            XHR = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Your navigator is old to run objets XMLHTTPRequest...");
        XHR = false;
    }
    return XHR;
}


function ajax_post(page, data) {

    var XHR = create_XHR();
    XHR.open("POST", page, true);
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (XHR.readyState === 4 && (XHR.status === 200 || XHR.status === 0)) {
            console.log("Success Transaction");
        }
    };
    XHR.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    XHR.send(data);
}


//Running the code :
//==================
var dataURL = me.video.getScreenCanvas().toDataURL();
ajax_post("http://www.mywebpage.com/image_upload.php", {"imgdata":dataURL});
```

---

Modify the cors http :
in the server PHP add this in first of your page "image_upload.php":

```
//Part added by ilyas :
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
//End of part.
```

Comment: Hi Ilyas! I did test your code last friday but StackOverflow was in read mode while I was working, so I couldn't answer you... The result is the same: the PHP file is unable to retrieve anything from the "POST". Although the "GET" method works fine, I tried different things for the "POST" and nothing seems to work... I have my Javascript files running in "CocoonJS" (which is an environment similar to PhoneGap, to make HTML and JS code run on mobile device apps) and my PHP files stored in my own server... What do you think might be happening?

Comment: To check whether the posted data was the cause of the problem I tested it sending a simple string "imateststring" instead of the dataURL, but nothing changed...

Comment: @Johanovski: so, I think you have a problem with "http cors header". this is a limitation generated were the resource in this case your HTML5 app and the server are not under the same host. but there is some solutions to resolve that :D. I will update the post.

Comment: Hi Ilyas! I added the code you suggested and also I appended a "charset=UTF-8" to the "setRequestHeader" call and now it is working! However, I've found that the only way my server is able to retrieve the data is through "$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];" insetad of "$_POST"... I read that CocoonJS (the framework I'm using to run JS on mobile devices) has some bugs relating AJAX and POST, so the whole thing might come from there... However, your answer has been really helpful, so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks for your time! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to configure you server apache in file httpd.conf

Under Apache, the limit is a configurable value, LimitRequestLine. Change this value to something larger than its default of 8190 if you want to support a longer request URI.

change :

```
LimitRequestLine 4094
```

to a value < 8190

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem... As I said, AJAX throw that error when trying to use its "GET" method, but now I'm trying to use the "POST" one (which should have no size limit)... Using this one, AJAX doesn't complain about anything being too long: it simply doesn't say nothing! What I'm wondering is why nothing is done in the PHP, but no AJAX error is returned either...

Comment: delete the line : req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  and tell me you have new changes

Comment: I deleted the line and nope, nothing changed... And the "var_dump" call suggested by CBroe is still returning an empty array...

Comment: @Johanovski: did you test my code  in the under post.